# php form not being processed through ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I've a form where I'm using ajax to submit it, but for some reason it is passing through ajax but its not being processed by php. I've tried using it without ajax and it works fine, but its is not processing php when processed through ajax request
This is my form

```
<form id="form" action="profile-settings" method="POST" name='form'>
      <div class="form-group">
           <label>Name</label>
           <input type="text" name="name" class="form-control" value="<?php echo $user->userName(); ?>" <?php if($user->pro() == 0) echo 'disabled';  ?> />
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
           <label>Description/Bio</label>
           <input type="text" name="bio" class="form-control" value="<?php echo $user->bio(); ?>" />
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
           <label>Company</label>
           <input type="text" name="company" class="form-control" value="<?php echo $user->company(); ?>" data-role="tagsinput" data-maxtags="3" />
           <small class="form-text text-muted">Comma separated values, maximum 3 values</small>
      </div>
<button type="submit" class="btn d-block mx-auto mt-4">Save</button>
```

This is my ajax

```
<script>
        var form = $('#form');
            form.on('submit',(e) => {
                console.log('Doneee');
                e.preventDefault();
                var data = form.serialize();
                $.ajax({
                    type: 'POST',
                    url: form.attr('action'),
                    data: data,
                    cache: false,
                    contentType: false,
                    processData: false
                })
                .done(() => {
                    console.log('Doneeee');
                });
            });   
        </script>
```

I'm getting both the console logs without any issue, I even tried 'success' instead of '.done' but it doesn't works, the php backend is not being processed

And this is my form processing code, this is not being processed using ajax dont know why

```
 if(!empty($_POST)){
        $name = filter_var($_POST['name'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
        $bio = filter_var($_POST['bio'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
        $company = explode(',', trim(filter_var($_POST['company'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING)));

        echo 'Doneeeee';
}
```

Help would be appreciated!

**Finally solved it!!
Used this library/code
jQuery Ajax Form Plugin
http://malsup.com/jquery/form/**

Comment: `action="profile-settings.php"` need to give `.php` ??

Comment: Open the network tab in your browsers dev console, submit the form and you should see if it makes the request, what it sends and what the response is.

Comment: I would also recommend adding the above js-code inside `$(function () {  ...your code...  })` to make sure everything has been properly loaded before creating the event listeners.

Comment: If your php `if(!empty($_POST))` is not "being processed" (as stated), then it's not even getting that far, so not much point worrying about what happens after that.

Comment: I've used .htaccess to hide .php so I didn't added it in action attribute

Comment: Tried everything but nothing helps

Comment: Put your php filename in `action` attribute

Comment: Your question was not solved. All that has been done is that you are using someones plugin that knows how to submit a form properly using ajax. It is always best to learn how to do something this simple yourself so you are prepared for the future.

Comment: I know, but I've trying to do it since a week, and I'm frustated. I posted it so others could get help from it.

Answer (score 0):

As a starter, check if action url is correct and not response 404 in browser console. After this, if you want to print php echo, you must to create a response in your javascript

```
.done(function(response) { console.log(response) });
```

Where response is your echo in php.

```
if($_POST != null){
        $name = filter_var($_POST['name'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
        $bio = filter_var($_POST['bio'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
        $company = explode(',', trim(filter_var($_POST['company'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING)));

    echo 'POST pass correctly';
} else { echo "POST not received"; }
```